# Why no SIP facility in 13.04?

Tags: empathy

I was able to use my plusnet broadband phone in empathy 1204, but the facility doesn't seem to be available in 13.04.
I have checked that telepathy sofiasip is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try installing the package account-plugin-sip using your favorite package manager or type in the command line

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-sip
```

That should make the SIP option available in your accounts settings.